# Grails Validation : renderErrors not picking up after formRemote

Tags: grails, tags

This is in the gsp

```
<g:if test="${hasError}">
    <div class="errors">
        <g:renderErrors bean="${eventInstance}" />
    </div>
</g:if>
<g:else >
    <div id="messageBox" class="message" style="display:none;">
        <g:message code="legalevent.save.success" args="[entityName]" default="Event saved successfully" />
    </div>
</g:else>
<g:formRemote name="eventForm" id="eventForm" url="[controller : 'search', action : 'saveLegalEvent']"  
                  update="eventFormDiv" action="${createLink(controller: 'search', action: 'saveLegalEvent')}" method="POST"
                  onSuccess="jQuery('#messageBox').show()">
```

I am rendering a page for update with this :

```
def saveLegalEvent = {

    def paramsView = params
    def eventPattern = /(event\.).*/
    def event = LegalEvent.findByLevId(params["levId"])
    def corrTxt = params["corrTxt"] as CorrectionText
    if(corrTxt.getCorrId()){
        corrTxt = CorrectionText.findByCorrId(corrTxt.getCorrId())
    }
    event.setCorrTxt(corrTxt)
    event.properties = params["event"] 
    def dataList = []
    def hasError = false
    def validated = event.validate()
    validated &= event.validateHistoryParams()
    if(validated)
        event.save(flush:true)
    else 
        hasError = true
    def errorsView = event.errors
    render(view:'leform', model:[attributeDataInstanceList:event.tags, lecInstance:event.leCode, eventInstance:event, hasError: hasError])
}
```

validateHistoryParams validate some more params that are usually not needed in the domain class.

```
def validateHistoryParams = { ->
    if(!changeRef || !changeRef.trim()) {
        this.errors.rejectValue('changeRef', 'event.changeRef.blank')
    }
    if(!corrTxt || !(corrTxt.corrTxt.trim() || corrTxt.corrId )) {
        this.errors.rejectValue('corrTxt', 'event.corrTxt.null')
    }

    !(this.hasErrors())
}
```

The problem with all this is that the errors are not rendered in the gsp.
All other tags are rendered fine, when debugging I can see that the errors are actually in the error stack. But in the end, the tag isn't rendering them.

As you can see, there is no redirection, so I can't understand why the errors would somehow be erased between the response creation and the rendering ...

Answer (score 0):

In your Groovy code, parameter returned is named `hasError`, and GSP checks for `hasErrors`. I'd recommend not to use extra variables, and just query the bean itself in GSP.

I also believe that you need to have that errors div **inside** the formRemote element in order to re-render after form submission.

Comment: First thanks for your answer. I tried both with and without hasError and I also changed the parameter's name, to no avail. The hasError parameters is here because I want to display a generic message if the bean has no errors ("Updated successfully" or something). I also tested it directly with the <g:hasErrors> tag on the bean, and it doesn't work.

Comment: tl; dr; At the end of the controller closure bean has errors in the erros arraylist. In gsp, bean errors are not displayed, and hasError tag when used treats bean as if it doesn't have any.

Comment: What if you render `${eventInstance.hasErrors()}`?
Is `eventFormDiv` anclosing the whole quoted GSP?

Comment: Actually, the errors have displayed once or two times while I was testing (completely randomly). The css class error is displayed if ${hasError(bean: eventInstance field: property)} returns true.  The problem is really that when the gsp is rendered, the errors somehow disappear. What I'm thinking is that, when it iterates over errors there is an uncaught exception somehow and it acts as if there are none ...

Comment: Maybe I should replicate the renderError and hasError tags and debut them myself ?

Comment: Good idea, at least for debugging purpose. Maybe some error's toString() throws an exception or something.